# How to vertically center a div with respect to the remaining height

Tags: html, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I made a webpage with a "sticky" footer(the footer is at the bottom of content if the content is large, or at the bottom of the viewport if the content is small) by using flexbox. I am now trying to make it so the content will be at the center of the remaining height(vh - height of navbar - height of footer) if the content is small enough. Below is an image to demostrate what I just said.
[image: Blue = navbar, green = content, red = footer]

Here is my code.

```
<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column full-height">
            <div id="div-top" class="d-flex flex-column" style="flex: 2">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                            <img class="logo d-inline-block align-top" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-256.png" width="30" height="30"> Brand</a>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="ml-auto navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="false" href="/about">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="false" href="/aaar">Ada</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="false" href="/bbbr">sdfsdfs</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <br>
                <div class="container d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center h-100" id="div-1">
                    <div class="row w-100">
                        <div class="text-center col col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                            <img class="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-256.png" width="256" height="256" alt="logo">
                            <h2 class="pt-2 pb-3 font-weight-normal">Description</h2>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                                <p>description</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="pt-4 text-muted">v1.0.0</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-none d-lg-block col col-lg-6">test</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="text-center container">
                    <span class="d-block">Copyright &copy; 2018</span>
                    <span class="text-muted">Some text here</span>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
#div-1 {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.full-height {
    height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1.2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

The height of the content won't change, I'm just trying to support multiple screen sizes. I have encountered 2 problems by using this approach. First, it does not work on landscape mode on mobile(emulated using chrome dev tools). Second, the navbar shrinks in height.

jsfiddle is available [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mq44nx78/1/). You can also compare it with [the original version](https://jsfiddle.net/mq44nx78/). Adding `/embedded/result/` to the end of the url will open the result in fullscreen. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the following it will work as you asked for:

- change to `min-height: 100vh` in the `.full-height` rule
- remove `align-items-center`/`h-100` and add `m-auto` in the `id="div-1"` elements class list

*Do note, the `<br>` you had after the `</nav>` in the markup is invalid, so i removed it. If you want a gap there, use margin's padding's*

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mq44nx78/4/)

Stack snippet

```css
#div-1 {
  background-color: #00ff00;
}

.full-height {
    min-height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
    margin: auto auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1.2rem;
    padding-bottom: 1.2rem;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="app">
    <div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-column full-height">
            <div id="div-top" class="d-flex flex-column" style="flex: 2">
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                            <img class="logo d-inline-block align-top" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-256.png" width="30" height="30"> Brand</a>
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                            <ul class="ml-auto navbar-nav">
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="false" href="/about">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="false" href="/aaar">Ada</a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" aria-current="false" href="/bbbr">sdfsdfs</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center m-auto" id="div-1">
                    <div class="row w-100">
                        <div class="text-center col col-md-12 col-lg-6">
                            <img class="logo" src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/new-google-logo-2015/400/new-google-favicon-256.png" width="256" height="256" alt="logo">
                            <h2 class="pt-2 pb-3 font-weight-normal">Description</h2>
                            <div>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add</a>
                                <p>description</p>
                            </div>
                            <p class="pt-4 text-muted">v1.0.0</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="d-none d-lg-block col col-lg-6">test</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="text-center container">
                    <span class="d-block">Copyright &copy; 2018</span>
                    <span class="text-muted">Some text here</span>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are a wizard!